# Can't get echo form_open to work - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm quite new to CodeIgniter. I've created this form, but clicking on either of the buttons doesn't run the controller method defined in echo form_open. Clicking on either submit button does nothing at all.

```
    <?php echo form_open('home/login'); ?>

      <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
      <input type="text" size="30" name="username" value="<?php if (get_cookie('username')) { echo get_cookie('username'); } ?>" style="text-transform:uppercase;"/><br/>

      <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
      <input type="text" size="30" name="email" value="<?php if (get_cookie('email')) { echo get_cookie('email'); } ?>" style="text-transform:uppercase;"/><br/>

      <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
      <input type="password" size="30" name="password" value="<?php if (get_cookie('password')) { echo get_cookie('password'); } ?>" style="text-transform:uppercase;"/><br/>

      <input type="checkbox" id="cookiecheck" name="cookiecheck" value="Remember">
      <label for="cookiecheck" <?php if (get_cookie('username')) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>REMEMBER_ME</label><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="LOG_IN"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="CREATE_ACCOUNT"/>


    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The login method I want to run is just:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function login(){
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
 }
```

My default_controller is already to set to 'home' by the way. 
If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Do you have any errors

Comment: Nope, if I click either of the buttons there's no response whatsoever

Comment: "Does nothing" sounds strange. Have you checked whether there is any JS handler blocking the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the `url`  and `form` helpers from the function where you load that view.

```
$this->load->helper(array("url", "form"));
```

And change the following

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('home/login')); ?>
//make sure you set the base_url properly
```

If it didn't work , simple replace it with

```
<form action="<?=base_url('home/login');?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

open your autoload file then load the html helper

application/config/autoload.php

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url_helper','form', 'html', 'url');`

Comment: Modify url_helper to url and try again

Answer (score 0):

Set the base_url in application/config/config.php.

```
$config["base_url"] = "http://localhost/project_folder/";
```

In your View change the form tag as shown bellow:

```
 <?php echo form_open(base_url("home/login")) ?>
```

good luck